# Recursive lock() call in g++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, c++14

Why does the following code result in a deadlock in g++ 5.4.0?

```
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;
    m.lock();
    m.lock();
}
```

As far as I know, this code should result in an exception according to the Standard:

> 30.4.1.2 Mutex types [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]
>
> 6 The expression m.lock() shall be well-formed and have the following
>   semantics:
>
> [...]
>
> 12 Throws: system_error when an exception is required (30.2.2).
>
> 13 Error conditions:
>
> (13.1) — operation_not_permitted — if the thread does not have the
>   privilege to perform the operation.
>
> (13.2) — resource_deadlock_would_occur — if the implementation detects
>   that a deadlock would occur.
>
> (13.3) — **device_or_resource_busy — if the mutex is already locked and
>   blocking is not possible**.

What's wrong then? Is it a bug in the library?

Comment: What happens when you use `std::lock_guard` to do the same thing? It might be that `lock` has a few details left unspecified like detecting recursion on the same thread.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Edited

Comment: The requires clause specifies the precondition for calling the function (7.5.1.4(3.1)). If it's not met, you have UB (7.6.4.11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour, because you are violating a precondition ([thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]):

> The expression `m.lock()` shall be well-formed and have the following semantics:
>
> *Requires:* If `m` is of type `std::mutex` [...], the calling thread does not own the mutex.

Comment: Why does it have the "device_or_resource_busy" error condition then?

Comment: @FrozenHeart That's when another thread attempt to lock the mutex, but can't be blocked.

Comment: I thought that the `lock()` should throw an exception if one of the error conditions is met. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Yes.

Comment: @Kerrek SB What do those error conditions mean then?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Could you please post that as a separate question?

Comment: Could you quote the Standard where it says that violating the precondition is UB?

Comment: @FrozenHeart _[structure.requirements]_ : _Requirements describe constraints that **shall be met** by a C++ program_

Comment: @FrozenHeart:  [res.on.required]. Note that the *Throws* element doesn't include the thread ownership as one of the valid reasons to throw an exception.

Comment: "Some functions described in this Clause are specified to throw exceptions of type system_error (19.5.7).
**Such exceptions shall be thrown if any of the function’s error conditions is detected** [...]". No?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: The Requires clause does not describe errors. It describes *preconditions*. Unless the Throws element says specifically that there's an exception when a particular precondition is violated (like in `vector::at`), then violation of that precondition is UB.

Comment: @FrozenHeart eror condition != requirement. If your code violates requirement, you can throw out everything written in standard. There is no restriction on UB. Your code as posted didn't trigger any actual error conditions. I doubt you can trigger `device_or_resource_busy` in userspace code on any modern hosted implementation.

Answer (score 0):

That exception was removed from `std::mutex` by [Library Issue #2309](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2309), so perhaps g++ 5.4 is just up-to-date.

Comment: So I was right guessing that the `lock()` should throw an exception if it locks the same mutex in the same thread? Because other people suggest other reasons